# How to limit size of cfdump for entities

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Is there away to limit size of cfdump when we're dumping an ORM entity? It seems that cfdump will try to load and display ALL entities related/associated to (as defined in many-to-one or one-to-many relationships) the entity being dumped. Sometimes dumping one single entity can lead to an output of more than 100mb (that's megabytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ef7.html), it looks like what you are looking for is the `top` parameter.

```
<cfdump  
    var = "#variable#" 
    output = "browser|console|file" 
    format = "text|html" 
    abort = "true|false"> 
    label = "text" 
    metainfo = "yes|no" 
    top = "number of rows|number of levels" 
    show = "columns|keys" 
    hide = "columns|keys" 
    keys = "number of keys to display for structures" 
    expand = "yes|no"  
    showUDFs = "yes|no">
```

> top Optional 9999 The number of rows to display. For a structure, this is the number of nested levels to display.

It's been a long time since I've used CFM, but you may also be interested in `keys`

> keys Optional 9999 For a structure, the number of keys to display.